# Url rewrite wordpress post with argument

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, urlrewriter

I have created a page with wordpress which have an argument:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?pagename=holiday&place=london
```

When i put on the permalink option in dashboard, i obtain this url:

```
/holiday/?place=london
```

I would like to have simply this:

```
`http://www.website.com/london/`
```

I have tried to modify the htaccess file.

Comment: Have you tried the permalink option in settings?

Comment: can you share your complete .htaccess file ?

Comment: Yes i have tried to active the permalink option in wordpress. This is my htaccess: Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?pagename=holiday&place=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]